# Do you know of any .NET components for creating Distance Matrices / Routing graphs?

Tags: .net, components, graph-theory

Based on geographical data in classic GIS formats. These matrices are a basic input for different vehicle routing problems and such. They can usually be produced an best time or shortest distance basis.

Answer (score 2):

[QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph)

Answer (score 0):

[ThinkGeo](http://thinkgeo.com/) has a routing extension that you can use to build a matrix with. This does involve some extra work.